# Extracting application code from .apk file

Tags: android, load, dalvik, dex

So, I'm trying to use a running application and have it access code of a not yet installed application through its .apk file. I need to access things such as the secondary applications packagename, provider, bundles, data, etc all without installing it onto the phone.

So far from what I understand I can use either one of two things.

1) dexClassLoader. With this option I need to be able to access the .apk file from some sort of storage such as an SD card.

2) pathClassLoader. Seems like the correct option here. Can use JAR/ZIP/APK files with this option.

Essentially I'm trying to load the second application into the first one by binding its code to a running process, I'm just having trouble accessing its code without decompiling it. I guess my question is should I be using/trying the first or second option here, or is a third option available?

Answer (score 0):

While you can dynamically load code from the second application using dexClassLoader, etc., you cannot dynamically add new components to your application. Any component must be statically declared in the AndroidManifest.xml.

So you cannot, for example, "import" an activity from the second apk into your main application. You can access the class for that Activity, but you can't directly start an activity using it.

Depending on your requirements, it might be possible to create a "placeholder" activity in your main application, which creates an instance of the Activity class from the secondary apk and forwards all method calls to that instance. In general, I would not actually suggest this. I suspect it would be very difficult (if not impossible in some cases) to actually do correctly.

Comment: Thanks. From a paper I read a few people bound a not yet installed applications code to a running process.

My goal is not to start the activity itself (however, that could be helpful), but rather do the second option you suggested. I realize it'll be nearly impossible, if possible at all, but I still want to try using some of the native methods to do so and I'm having trouble accessing certain information needed to do calls such as bindApplication() etc without actually installing the second .apk file.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100863/android-instrumentation-execstartactivity-parameters

Comment: @Pulkit - good question, upvoted. I can't help though, sorry :)